# Swift + Parse: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

So I have a Swift application that I am working on (in Xcode 7.3).

It uses Parse and in it I have a function that is generating the error message stated in the title.

The code appears as follows;

```
@IBAction func callUber(sender: AnyObject) {

    let riderRequest = PFObject(className:"riderRequest")
    riderRequest["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    riderRequest["location "] = PFGeoPoint(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude)

    riderRequest.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {

            self.callUberButton.setTitle("Cancel Uber", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        } else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not call Uber", message: "Please try again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
    }


}
```

Now somewhere in this code nil is being applied to a value, and this causes the error message (or so I think). I have been looking around on SO for solutions to this problem, however I could not find any similar threads for this error message and Swift, only Objective-C.

I'm guessing that I have to introduce some sort of error handling or check where I make sure that the value of the object is not nil, however I cant seem to figure out where, or how to apply this.

The error is only triggered when I press the "callUber" button, and the full output from the debug console follows below.

```
2016-04-15 12:21:01.900 ParseStarterProject-Swift[8781:2591354] ***             Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ca98d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010eca0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ca98cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010c1042a8 -[PFObject(Private) _setObject:forKey:onlyIfDifferent:] + 122
4   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010c107d01 -[PFObject setObject:forKey:] + 53
5   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010c107d46 -[PFObject setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 50
6   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010c0c847f _TFC25ParseStarterProject_Swift19RiderViewController8callUberfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 671
7   ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010c0c89d6 _TToFC25ParseStarterProject_Swift19RiderViewController8callUberfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
8   UIKit                               0x000000010d726a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
9   UIKit                               0x000000010d899e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
10  UIKit                               0x000000010d89a143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
11  UIKit                               0x000000010d899263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
12  UIKit                               0x000000010d79999f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
13  UIKit                               0x000000010d79a6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
14  UIKit                               0x000000010d745dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
15  UIKit                               0x000000011dfe0b15 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 77
16  UIKit                               0x000000010d71f553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9be301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9b422c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9b36e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9b30f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111eb0ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
22  UIKit                               0x000000010d724f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
23  ParseStarterProject-Swift           0x000000010c0cc712 main + 114
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f7a792d start + 1
25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things that may be the issue:

Double check your class name is "riderRequest", I think "RiderRequest" could possibly be the actual name.

Second is to check all your key names are correct by going to the parse dashboard and having a look at your class

Last thing is to confirm that all your values for things like username and latitude and longitude are not nil before setting them.

Maybe try:

```
if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username && latitude != nil && longitude != nil {

    riderRequest.setObject(username, forKey: "username")
    riderRequest.setObject(PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), forKey: "location")

//then run the rest of the code as you have been
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was the username variable that was the issue. The log-in view controller was not "initial view controller" causing me to open the app without signing in first. Silly me.
I did however encouter a new parse error after solving the first one; **Swift[8903:2666826] [Error]: invalid key name: location  (Code: 105, Version: 1.12.0)
5**
Now I know that "location" is a column in the riderRequest class so thats not the issue, but I'm not sure if that is what this error message is complaining about either.

Comment: Ah, in that case check on your parse dashboard what you named your location attribute.

Comment: I figured that one out pretty quick, though. the code had a whitespace after location, so instead of looking for "location" it was looking for "location ". Haha, sometimes these typos introduce some funny bugs. Thank you so much for the help Olivier :)

Comment: No problem at all! It's always nice when the issue is fixed quickly :)